# Input value based on query string

Tags: php

How could I pass a query string value such as `domain.com/register?invite=MR5OMxTyjYmTjcwNTyQjTZMyY5YY` into a input box on a page?

For example say I had this: `<input type="text" name="invite" value="" />`

I'm using PHP

To clarify what I mean, if a person loaded that URL, then the value would be automatically filled in with the query string of invite.

Comment: notice `value=""` part in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="invite" value='<?php echo $_GET["invite"]; ?>'  />
```

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks for selecting this as answer, but what @Jacob Relkin has posted would be the best answer (It takes care of whether the key exists in the get collection and also escapes it for any special characters.).

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
<?php $invite = (array_key_exists('invite', $_GET)) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['invite']) : ''; ?>
<input type="text" name="invite" value="<?php echo $invite; ?>" />
```

Comment: Just don't forget to sanitize the `$invite` value before displaying it.

Comment: It won't throw an error if you access $_GET['invite'] without it existing, it will just output an empty string. It seems like PHP convention is usually to do the laziest thing.

Comment: That is because PHP is for lazy people :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="invite" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['register'])) echo $_GET['register']; ?>" />
```

This isn't secure at all, but it gives you a start.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching the invite key with $_GET['invite'] from the address bar (validate it first of course to prevent XSS attacks ;) ) and then place it in your input field within that value part as `$invite` for example so you end up with `value="$invite"`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" name="invite" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['invite']; ?>" />`

Comment: What's the difference between GET and REQUEST for getting the query string?

Comment: REQUEST puts GET and POST together so you don't have to differentiate if the variable came from the URL query string (GET) or via a form post (POST).